Does this carbon scratch affect frame integrity?
I have a carbon mountain bike that has gotten a scratch on the underside of the down tube, right by the head tube. The scratch has worn through the paint. Does it affect the structure of the bike or is it just cosmetic? And is it safe to ride?




Just remember to not trust the assessment of any random stranger on the internet about safety relevant issues.

You're probably fine. Abrasion damage is significantly less dangerous than an impact-related chip or crack.

In the first 2 pics it looks like there's also some buckling in the middle of the tube, could also be just the paint though.

You do mean the big flat spot of abrasion, right? Looks like it has only abraded through the paint and primer and not yet damaged any carbon layers? If that’s the case then structurally it’s perfectly fine.
You just have to make sure the abrasion doesn’t continue (usually caused by brake lines, shifter cables or handlebar bags rubbing against the frame). Paint over it and then put some protective tape on top.

I think OP's asking about the whitish scratch because its central-frame in the photos.  But you're right, the rubbed area is significant too, and probably through more layers than the scratch.

I think Michael's right about which scratch, but in any case, neither one is dangerous yet.
